# Random subsequence fasta sequence and change sequence name

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta, bioconductor

I have a fasta file (fas2), which has about 1000 fasta sequences and here are couple example of fasta sequence:

```
>gi|108863165-BAdV-2
ATGGCTACTCCTTCGATGATGCCGCAGTGGTCTTACATGCACATCGCCGGGCAGGATGCCTCCGA
>gi|108863163-BAdV-1
ATGGCGACGCCGTCGATGATGCCCCAGTGGTCGTACATGCACATCGCCGGGCAGGATGCCTCAGA
```

I looked up online and see many tutorials use readDNAStringSet to read the fasta file. So I use this comment to read my file:

```
fas3 <- readDNAStringSet(fas2, "fasta")
```

It does create a data.frame like structure (but it is not data.frame) to view the fasta file. My questions are whether there is any function in R I can randomly sample 500 fasta sequences out of fas3? Also, if I want to rename a specific fasta name such as (gi|108863165-BAdV-2 to BAdV-2), how do I do that? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fas3` follows a 'vector-like' interface, rather than a data.frame, so you could sample sequences by generating 500 numbers from the length of the object, and using those to subset

```
fas3.subset = fas3[sample(length(fas3), 500)]
```

Use the accessor `names()<-` to update names, e.g.,

```
 names(fas3) = sub("gi|108863165-", "", names(fas3)
```

This is illustrated on the help page `?DNAStringSet`. See also the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org) for a more appropriate forum for questions about Bioconductor packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the command line — and if you know that your FASTA headers and sequences are pairs of lines — you can use [*sample*](https://github.com/alexpreynolds/sample) to sample pairs of lines.

For example, to sample 500 sequences without replacement:

```
$ sample --lines-per-offset=2 --sample-size=500 fas2.fa > fas2.sample.fa
```

Run `sample --help` for more options.

You could use `sed` to substitute names:

```
$ sed 's/gi|108863165-BAdV-2/BAdV-2/' fas2.fa > fas2.modified.fa
```